# How to pass out parameter in JNI

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I have my below java code

```
public class JNIWrapper {

static{




    System.loadLibrary("JNIDemo");
}

public native String get_error_string(int error_code);
public native int  start(Param_s params);
public native int cancel(String cookies);
public native int get_file_name(String cookies,String fileName);

public native int get_status(String cookies,int percentage_complete);
```

}
Below is my generated .H file

```
 /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class demo_JNIWrapper */

#ifndef _Included_demo_JNIWrapper
#define _Included_demo_JNIWrapper
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_demo_JNIWrapper_get_1error_1string
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_demo_JNIWrapper_1start
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jobject);


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_demo_JNIWrapper_cancel
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_demo_JNIWrapper_getfile_1name
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring, jstring);


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_demo_JNIWrapper_get_1status
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Incase of lets say get_status ,i want to have the percentage_complete as the out parameter and it returns say 0,with this I will have in return both percentage_complete(As it's in out parameter ) a return value .

Any help would be highly appreciated and would be really helpful

NOTE:I cannot use struct for this ie:I can'y encapsulate both percentage_complete and return output in a struct and return that struct)

Comment: There are no 'out' parameters in Java, and therefore none in JNI native methods either.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return two things:

1. Error indication.
2. An integer value.

Return an `Integer` object on success, `null` on failure.  Change

```
public native int get_status(String cookies,int percentage_complete);
```

to

```
public native Integer get_status(String cookies);
```

This will change your generated header file, and you'll have to make the corresponding changes to your C code.

Comment: But this will only return an Integer,I want to return a)error_indication b)out parameter is interger valuer(percentage complete)

Comment: If you return `null` instead of an `Integer` **object**, that will be your error indication.

Comment: No ,my percentage complete can be 70% with error indication as 0 and it can also be 100% with error_indication as 80% and it can also be 50% with error_indication as 1

Comment: It smells like [Primitive Obsession](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/primitive-obsession).